# font awesome icons are squares when uploaded to a server

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a website theme on my local machine. It works fine except when i upload it to a remote server.

What doesn't work is the font awesome icons. They all become tiny squares

I have gone through each of the files to make sure they're the same

```
<link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The href path has to be relative to the file the 'link' tag was included in. So if the index.html file is in the same folder as the 'vendor' folder, the href path would start with './vendor/...', where '.' is the current path. If your vendor folder is a folder above your .html file, then the href path would be '../vendor/...', where '..' is the folder above your current path. '...' just means etc.

Comment: Actually i had made the mistake of referencing the links remotely but the site was still on my local machine. But soon as i moved the site to the server then everything worked

Answer (score 1):

Try `<link href="/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`